# background image in a email with a td

Tags: html, css, gmail

Trying to get a background image on the go for a cell of a table so I can display dynamic text over it

I tried :

```
<td style="background-image:url('bla...
```

It ain't working? Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you set your mail client to download external images automatically?  Background images don't get a free pass around privacy settings.

Comment: Please post entire code. The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a Base64 encode on the image ([Base64 Online](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)), and then add the string generated to the css rule. This will also add more space to the email about 33%.

Answer (score 7):

```
<td background="sample.jpg">
```

is accually best solution. It's the most compatible way to fit all email clients. CSS solution will not work in Google mail for example. And that's pretty popular way of viewing emails these days.

Answer (score 1):

You want background image to be displayed for a particular cell of table ?

If that's the case, use this

```
<TD BACKGROUND="sample.jpg" >
```

Comment: That's not a good solution, because CSS styles should be used.

Comment: Did the OP exclusively mention that he wants CSS ? He's not even displaying entire code ? What exactly he wants ?

Comment: The OP pertains to styling an email in HTML, best not to use too much CSS since email clients tend not to be very good browsers.

Comment: Sorry Alp, you are incorrect sir! Best to use as little CSS as possible when building emails. I have tested <td background="sample.jpg"> via litmus and it has the most support across the board.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tags, it looks like you are targeting gmail. Gmail works by using the `background="image.jpg"` attribute (at least if you apply it to a table, but td should be fine, too).

If you'd like to include other clients, too, you may use a mixed approach with the background-attribute and some css (check out [this article](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3170/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/) with examples). Some clients (Lotus-...) are very difficult to cover though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td background="sample.jpg" >
```

If you want to display an image for a particular cell then the best solution for this is: